# merge unequal data frames in R and remove unmatched columns

Tags: r, merge

I have 2 data frames of different column length. Say, `df1` has 3 columns (A,C,D) of 10 rows, `df2` has 5 columns (A,B,C,D,E) of 3 rows. How do I merge them together and remove the columns that don't match from df2 (B an E), leaving just a `df` of 13 rows and 3 columns A,C,D?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `intersect` to find the columns in both data.frames,  then `rbind` the rows.

```
df1 = data.frame(A=1:10, C=11:20, E=21:30)
df2 = data.frame(A=101:103, B=111:113, C=121:123, 
    D=131:133, E=141:143)

InBoth = intersect(colnames(df1), colnames(df2))
df3=rbind(df1[,InBoth], df2[,InBoth])
df3
     A   C   E
1    1  11  21
2    2  12  22
3    3  13  23
4    4  14  24
5    5  15  25
6    6  16  26
7    7  17  27
8    8  18  28
9    9  19  29
10  10  20  30
11 101 121 141
12 102 122 142
13 103 123 143
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is perfect. I'll put this as answer in 4 minutes since yours is too quick :D

Answer (score 1):

This uses dplyr bind_rows (just because I use dplyr heavily)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b=11:15, c=21:25)
df2 <- data.frame(a = 101:106, b = 121:126, e = 141:146)
new_names <- intersect(names(df1), names(df2))
bind_rows(df1[,new_names], df2[,new_names])

#      a   b
# 1    1  11
# 2    2  12
# 3    3  13
# 4    4  14
# 5    5  15
# 6  101 121
# 7  102 122
# 8  103 123
# 9  104 124
# 10 105 125
# 11 106 126
```

Comment: Makes more sense to write new_names only once, I think: `bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% select_(.dots = new_names)`

Comment: Taking @Frankspoint a little further makes for a fairly readable one-liner `bind_rows(df1, df2)[,intersect(names(df1), names(df2))]` - this works with dplyr::bind_rows but not rbind because bind_rows combines different columns